# Convert BYTE array into unsigned long long int

Tags: c++

I'm trying to convert a BYTE array into an equivalent unsigned long long int value but my coding is not working as expected. Please help with fixing it or suggest an alternative method for the same.

Extra Information: These 4 bytes are combined as a hexadecimal number and an equivalent decimal number is an output. Say for a Given byteArray= {0x00, 0xa8, 0x4f, 0x00}, Hexadecimal number is 00a84f00 and it's equivalent decimal number is 11030272.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

typedef unsigned char BYTE;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  BYTE byteArray[4] = { 0x00, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00 };
  std::string str(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&byteArray[0]), 4);
  std::cout << str << std::endl;

  unsigned long long ull = std::strtoull(str.c_str(), NULL, 0);
  printf ("The decimal equivalents are: %llu", ull);


  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I'm getting the following output:

```
The decimal equivalents are: 0
```

While the expected output was:

```
The decimal equivalents are: 2048
```

Comment: Use `memcpy()`.

Comment: Wait, what? How do you expect a string full of special characters to be convertible to `2048`? At least use `{0x32,0x30,0x34,0x38}`.

Comment: Also consider using the C++ variants (C++11 and higher)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `std::strtoull(str.c_str(), NULL, 0);`, its first argument supplied is **equivalent to an empty string**, as string is essentially a null-terminated sequence of characters.

Second, `std::strtoull()` does not convert with byte sequences, it converts with the literal meaning of strings. i.e. you'll get `2048` with `std::strtoull("2048", NULL, 10)`.

Another thing to note is that `unsigned long long` is a 64-bit data type, whereas your byte array only provides 32 bits. You need to fill the other 32 bytes with zero to get the correct result. I use a direct assignment, but you could also use `std::memset()` here.

What you want to do is:

```
ull = 0ULL;
std::memcpy(&ull, byteArray, 4);
```

Given your platform has [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), the result should be `2048`.

Comment: As this is [tag:c++], `std::fill` and `std::copy` would suit better.

Comment: @MárioFeroldi Looks like new stuff in C++17. Sorry I'm not quite familiar with whose ;(

Comment: These algorithms have been on the standard for years; they're not C++17 features.

Comment: @MárioFeroldi Can you please provide an example

Comment: @user9059547 See [the answer](/a/48584380/5958455) below.

Comment: I'm getting error: 'memcpy' is not a member of 'std' even after including string.h to my code.

Comment: @user9059547 You forgot `#include <cstdlib>` and `#include <cstring>`.

Comment: After I included <cstring> it works for the given set of output but not for another set byteArray= {0x00, 0xa8, 0x4f, 0x00}, Expected Output : 11030272

Comment: @user9059547 Your expected output is wrong. The byte array should have been `{0x00, 0x4f, 0xa8, 0x00}`. It's endian matter. See the link in the last paragraph.

Answer (score 3):

What you first must remember is that a string, is really a ***null-terminated*** string. Secondly, a string is a string of *characters*, which is not what you have. The third problem is that you have an array of four bytes, which corresponds to an unsigned 32-bit integer, and you want an (at least) 64-bit types which is 8 bytes.

You can solve all these problems with a temporary variable, a simple call to [`std::memcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy), and an assignment:

```
uint32_t temp;
std::memcpy(&temp, byteArray, 4);
ull = temp;
```

Of course, this assumes that the [*endianness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) is correct.

---

Note that I use `std::memcpy` instead of `std::copy` (or `std::copy_n`) because `std::memcpy` is explicitly mentioned to be able to bypass strict aliasing this way, while I don't think the `std::copy` functions are. Also the `std::copy` functions are more for copying *elements* and not anonymous bytes (even if they can do that too, but with a clunkier syntax).

Comment: If you use the right iterator (`char *`, `unsigned char *`, `signed char *`, or `std::byte *`), then strict aliasing isn't a problem because of the property of these pointers.

Comment: I'm getting error: 'memcpy' is not a member of 'std' even after including string.h to my code.

Comment: @MárioFeroldi Well, `std::memcpy` (or `std::memmove`) is explicitly cited in the standard (§ 6.9 Types, par. 2,3 and footnotes 43, 44) for this very purpose. IMHO, it's cleaner too (even if you have to include `<cstring>`), but that's a matter of opinion...

Comment: @MárioFeroldi The generated assembly *may* (without optimizations) also be different: https://godbolt.org/g/awnj4T

Comment: @Bob__ `std::copy` may do more than just byte-copy, because it may just select the appropriate algorithm for the set of iterators it's given.

Answer (score 2):

Given the answers are using `std::memcpy`, I want to point out that there's a more idiomatic way of doing this operation:

```
char byteArray[] = { 0x00, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00 };
uint32_t cp;
std::copy(byteArray, byteArray + sizeof(cp), reinterpret_cast<char*>(&cp));
```

[`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) is similar to `std::memcpy`, but is the C++ way of doing it.

Note that you need to cast the address of the output variable `cp` to one of: `char *`, `unsigned char *`, `signed char *`, or `std::byte *`, because otherwise the operation wouldn't be byte oriented.

Comment: This code seems to work fine for the given set of byteArray but if I change my byteArray, it is not working as expected. :(

Comment: BYTE byteArray[] = {0x00, 0xa8, 0x4f, 0x00}; Expected output is: 11030272

Comment: @user9059547 if your architecture is little-endian, then it's being interpreted as `0x004fa800`. Swap `0xa8` with `0x4f` and you should get 11030272.